# How do I populate a UL's list items with values from a JSON without creating dupliates?

Tags: javascript, json

I have data in a JSON format like this:

```
[ 
 { year: 2012, name: "Foo"}, 
 { year: 2011, name: "Foobar"},
 { year: 2010, name: "Foobar again"},
 { year: 2012, name: "Baz"} 
]
```

Sometimes a year will be repeated in the JSON. I want to build a navbar that displays some data corresponding to each year chosen.

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#2010">2010</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2011">2011</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2012">2012</a></li>
 <ul>
</nav>
```

How do I populate the list items in the nav in such a way that the years aren't repeated in it and duplicates do not reside in it?

Comment: If there is a duplicate, how do you know which one to keep?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, I only need one of each year for the nav. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the full answer:

```
var arr = [ 
  { year: 2012, name: "Foo"}, 
  { year: 2011, name: "Foobar"},
  { year: 2010, name: "Foobar again"},
  { year: 2012, name: "Baz"} 
];

// map all the years into an array
var years = arr.map(function (el) {
  return el.year.toString();
});

// remove all of the duplicates from the array
var deduped = years.filter(function(elem, pos) {
    return years.indexOf(elem) == pos;
});

// sort the array
deduped = deduped.sort();

// create a docfrag, append some new options to it
// and append it to the select element
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0, l = deduped.length; i < l; i++) {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = '#' + deduped[i];
  anchor.text = deduped[i];
  item.appendChild(anchor);
  frag.appendChild(item);
}

var select = document.querySelector('nav ul');
select.appendChild(frag);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YPU89/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the JSOn into javascript object list with JSON.parse(yourJSON);
Then you remove your duplicates and generate your list from the new array.